Blender auto saving before rendering
Is it possible to set up Blender to always save the blend file before starting render, so when I press render, it saves then it starts rendering? Many times I press render and it crashes right away and it removes the few changes that I have been making so I have to start again. Cause I have seen that after-effects does that. So if it can be a thing here as well.

you could write an own operator in python who does that and give it the same shortcut as render has.

I'll have to ask a friend for such a task, not familiar with coding. But it would be a big plus for me. Cause has been experiencing a lot of crashing for running out of GPU memory. But haven't saved my file.
